# Firebase storage - how to deny permission to access a file in storage to an unauthorised web user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Firebase storage docs suggest user access to files can be managed by setting Firebase storage rules. In practice, however, despite setting the storage rules to

```
request.auth.uid == userId;
```

anyone with the URL of the file in storage can still access it, authorised or not.

Does Firebase offer a solution to this reasonably frequent (and important) use case? If so, what is it? If not, why not and any workarounds? A web example would be great.

The docs don't provide any or I haven't managed to find them so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: As I said in your other question, the download URL is behaving as expected.  Anyone who has a download URL generated by a call to getDownloadUrl can get its contents, regardless of security rules.  Please edit your question to focus on the problem you want to solve, not the idea that the rules aren't working the way you expect.

Comment: Practically speaking, you're going to have a hard time with this. You'll probably have to create your own backend API endpoint that can accept the user's auth token, and check (in code) if the user can download the file, then proxy the contents of that file from Cloud Storage back the the user.

Comment: Sorry Doug, the security rules (the way they are presented at least) are supposed to deal with an issue like this. If one can't restrict access to a file just to an authorised user, then it's a major flaw in the design of the authorisation. My expectations were set at a high level by the security rules video in the docs.  there was not a hint that this is not possible

Comment: As I said in your other question, you would use the SDK to download the file on Android or iOS in a way that observes security rules (not using a download URL), but that is not supported for the web.  If you have product feedback or requests, you can contact Firebase support directly, but the download URLs have been working like this for years, so it's not likely to change soon.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: That's disappointing. Basically, people are not yet able to use firebase storage for storing anything sensitive to a particular user. I thought the storage solution was more mature than that and the security video in the docs is dated 2016!

You mentioned backend workarounds. How would you deal with a file url for the front-end? It can't be a firebase storage one as it's exposed. Where are people storing the files then that only the user can access?

Comment: I gave you my recommendation in the second comment.  Please send your feedback to Firebase support.

Comment: I'm not familiar with proxying the contents of a file from Cloud Storage, Doug. Have you seen an implementation you can share? Hopefully, we're not the only two people reading firebase-storage things on here. Perhaps, someone from the Firebase team might jump in at some point, lol!